# Angular 2 Dart: How to add body class from inside component?

Tags: css, dart, angular2-template, angular-dart, angular2-dart

My Angular 2 Dart application has many nested components. If a certain property of one of my components is set to true, a popup is shown.

If this popup is shown I want to add a class to the document body.

Pseudo code example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body class="">
<app-component>
<home-component> <!-- with routers -->
<inner-component>
<popup-component>
// if I am active I want to add a body class
</popup-component>
</inner-component>
</home-component>
</app-component>
</body>
</html>
```

Simple reason: If the popup component is displayed I want to disable body scrolling (`overflow-x:hidden;`). The popup component is shown if the property `bool show_popup` within `popup_component.dart` is set to true.

Unfortunatly in CSS - as far as i know - there is no selector to check this ([Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)) - otherwise I would say something like

```
body:has(.my_popup)
```

in the main.css file or something similar.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two way.

You can use

```
@HostBinding('class.someclass') bool isSomeClass = true;
```

in the root component if it has

```
selector: 'body'
```

or

```
document.querySelector('body').classes.add('someClass');
```

You can use `:host-context(...)` to style a component depending on a selector matching a parent

```
:host-context(body.someClass) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

will make the background color red when the `body` element has `class="someClass"` set.

Comment: :host-context(body.someClass) works perfect!! thanks